# Set .png default compression in Photoshop CS6

Tags: adobe-photoshop, compression, png, photoshop-cs6

Is there a possibility to set .png  default compression options to "**NONE / fast**"?

Whenever I try to save as **.png**, the default option is set to "*smallest / slow*".